# How to Auto-Fill a Reverse Pair Combination in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image]

I am currently manually inputting my 'Y' and 'N' values into my Value column based on research.  However, to save time, I would like the value for the initial pair to be auto-filled for its reverse pairing.  For example, I gave the apple to orange pairing a value of 'Y'.  I would like to have auto-filled the orange to apple pairing with the same 'Y' value.  I thought of doing index match, but it doesn't take into consideration the combinations of pairings.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Thing is, if you put a static value into the `value` column, you're overwriting the formulas that would calculate the pairings.  You'd probably need a reference table somewhere, but you haven't given indication if 1) that's an option or 2) if there's a pattern for your ref data.

Comment: *"initial country pair"* Countries?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a formula, but here's a VBA solution - you could even turn this into a `Worksheet_Change` event which would constantly refresh values if you made an changes to the column itself.

As Marc said - you shouldn't really have a column with a mix of values and formulas (especially if it's reading off of itself, then you're going to run into a problem of **recursion**).

```
Option Explicit
Sub PopulateValue()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        If Cells(i, 3).Value = "" Then

            'Look for a true match
            For j = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If i <> j Then
                    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(j, 1).Value And _
                       Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value Then
                        If Cells(j, 3).Value <> "" Then
                            Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(j, 3).Value
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next j

            'Look for a reverse match
            For j = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                If i <> j Then
                    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value And _
                       Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 2).Value Then
                        If Cells(j, 3).Value <> "" Then
                            Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(j, 3).Value
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a worksheet formula. Assuming Header in row 1, data starting in row 2, and `Entity1`, `Entity2` and `Value` in columns `A`, `B` and `C`, respectively, put

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C2,MATCH(B3&"$"&A3,A$2:A2&"$"&B$2:B2,0)),"")
```

in `C3` as an array formula (`CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`) and fill down.

**Explanation**

The formula does an index/match like you considered. For the lookup part of the match it concatenates `Entity2` and `Entity` into a single string. There is an optional `$` delimiter between two two entities (explained below). For the array part of the match it `Entity1` and `Entity2` joined by the same delimiter. The array starts in the first data row and ends in the row above the current row.

If the match returns an index, that is plugged into `INDEX` along with the array of values up to the present one. If the match returns a #VALUE error, it gets caught by wrapping in an `IFERROR` function.

**Delimiter** Consider two pairs of `Entity1` and `Entity2`, the first pair being (pikes, peak) and the second being (pike, speak). Concatenating either of these without a delimiter gives "pikespeak" and could lead to an erroneous match. The delimiter guards against that. You can choose any string that down not occur in your data as a delimiter.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for this - I input the array formula in column C, however, when I input a new value into C, like 'Y' or 'N', the formula is erased and does not match up with its reverse pair.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @thedatasleuth. After putting in the formula, start at the top of the list and manually enter 'Y' or 'N'. All of the reverse-matches below will calculate to 'Y' or 'N'. Move to the next blank and manually enter another 'Y' or 'N'. More matches below get calculated. Continue down the list, manually updating blanks and skipping cells that are calculated.